# In Eclipse, why additional plugin break the Android plug-in?

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I had Eclipse running with the Android plug-in and I decided to add the Emacs plug-in. I downloaded and it worked. Then I decided to go back to the Eclipse key bindings and the Android plug-in disappeared. I could not update it, because Eclipse said it was installed, but it was not showing up in the menu.

I had to re download Eclipse, and reinstall the plug-in.

Why don't different plug-ins cooperate? I had the same issue when I tried to download the Blackberry plug-in alongside the Android plug-in (in different workspaces) and that also did not work. The only solution is to have two separate Eclipse each with a different plug-in.

Am i doing something wrong or is Eclipse that fragile!

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Do you have a particular problem you want help solving?  Or do you just want to complain?  If you want help you should describe in detail which plugins you are using, and what bad behavior you found when you installed them at the same time.

Comment: You should file this as a bug report on http://b.android.com - the plugin team would probably be interested.

Comment: Just want to complain and vent about losing a couple of hours. Installing the emacs plugin did not brake the android plugin but deinstalling it made it disappear and eclipse could not recover it. I had to reinstall eclipse in a new directory, download android ant and point it to the sdk. Similaraly, found out that i could not use one eclipse install with an android and blackberry plugins, i had two have two separate eclipse installs, each with it's own plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two installs of Eclipse, one for android and one for blackberry, this might not be the optimal way to do it, but it never gives me trouble. Aditionally the ADT likes eclipse 3.5 best so in case I ever do update the blackberry one, android still works.

Comment: That's what I also do, two separate Eclipse installs.

Comment: That's what i did in XP and MacOS. Two separate installs of Eclipse, in separate directories.